# DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) function not getting called

Tags: java, rabbitmq-exchange

I am trying to retrieve response from a rabbitmq queue, on the first go with the same code, I was able to retrieve the response correctly but whenever I run it the second or third time it does not call the `delivercallback` function where I am trying to retrieve the response

```java
DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
    String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");

    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");

};
boolean autoAck = true; // acknowledgment is covered below
channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, autoAck, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
```

Expected: Response should get printed which is there in DeliverCallback lambda expression.
Actual: DeliverCallback lambda expression not getting called that is why I am not able to retrieve response from rabbitmq queue

Comment: Please find below the full code:
 DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");

            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");

        };
        boolean autoAck = true; // acknowledgment is covered below
        channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, autoAck, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });

Answer (score 2):

Sending back an acknowledgement removes the message from queue, thus the message is not retrievable when consumer application is triggered for the second and the third time.

Comment: That is correct, autoAck=true "removes" the message from the queue. Still, the code picks up an output beforehand that it doesn't see (understood correctly?). I have the same problem: I print my result to the console and nothing appears...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private static void LogMsg(String msg) {
    System.out.println(msg);
}

// ...

DeliverCallback deliverCallback = new DeliverCallback() {
    public void handle(String s, Delivery delivery) throws IOException {
        LogMsg("s - "+s);
        LogMsg("Tag: "+delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag());

        String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), "UTF-8");
        LogMsg(message);
    }
};

channel.basicConsume(queueName, true, deliverCallback, new CancelCallback() {
    public void handle(String consumerTag) throws IOException {
    }
});
```

Comment: Please don't use Non-English as per Stackoveflow policy. If you want your answer to be helpful to others across the world then please use a universal language which can understandable by everyone.

Comment: Not work for me, same as lambda use. Callback never called, but the messages are consumed.